# Does flink reduce on the fly in batch mode

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-flink

According to the flink streaming documentation:

> The window function can be one of ReduceFunction, FoldFunction or
>   WindowFunction. The first two can be executed more efficiently (see
>   State Size section) because Flink can incrementally aggregate the
>   elements for each window as they arrive.

Does the same apply in the batch mode? In the example bellow, I'm reading ~36go of data from cassandra, but I expect the reduced output to be much smaller (~0.5go). Would running this job require flink to store the whole input in memory or is it smart enough to just iterate over it

```
DataSet<MyRecord> input = ...;
DataSet<MyRecord> sampled = input
        .groupBy(MyRecord::getSampleKey)
        .reduce(MyRecord::keepLast);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation on the Reduce Operation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#reduce-on-grouped-dataset) in Flink, I see the following:

> A Reduce transformation that is applied on a grouped DataSet reduces
>   each group to a single element using a user-defined reduce function.
>   For each group of input elements, a reduce function successively
>   combines pairs of elements into one element until only a single
>   element for each group remains.
>
> Note that for a ReduceFunction the keyed fields of the returned object
>   should match the input values. **This is because reduce is implicitly
>   combinable** and objects emitted from the combine operator are again
>   grouped by key when passed to the reduce operator.

If I am reading this correctly, Flink performs the reduce operation on *the mapper* side, and again on *the reducer* side, so the data that is actually emitted/serialized should be small.